# Declaring a global variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, global-variables

Is there a way to declare global variables in MATLAB?

Please don't respond with:

```
global x y z;
```

Because I can also read [the help files](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/global.html).

I've declared a global variable, `x`, and then done something like this:

```
function[x] = test()
    global x;
    test1();
end
```

Where the function `test1()` is defined as:

```
function test1()
    x = 5;
end
```

When I run `test()`, my output is `x = []`. Is there a way I can make it output the `x=5`, or whatever I define `x` to be in a separate function? In C, this would be an external variable, and I thought making it a global variable should accomplish just that.

Comment: +1 for being able to read the help files, at least until it says: ` However, if several functions, and possibly the base workspace, *all* declare a particular name as global, they all share a single copy of that variable.`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to declare `x` as a [global variable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html#f0-38470) in every scope (i.e. function/workspace) that you want it to be shared across. So, you need to write `test1` as:

```
function test1()
  global x;
  x = 5;
end
```

Comment: This is correct. However, the answer to the question "Hoe should I use globals in language X" is almost always "don't"

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: Agreed. Global variables are not pretty and are a big pain to keep track of, but in rare cases may be a necessary evil. If I knew more about what the OP's specific situation was (I think the above is a simplified example), I could probably suggest a better approach.

Comment: perhaps you could offer me some advice then. I wrote a program that is made up of a couple of `.m` files. The program takes a matrix A as an input, then passes it to one function, that function does something to the matrix, and passes it to another function which does another thing with the matrix A. Finally, we go back to the original matrix, it checks the outputted matrix, and then passes it to a last function to do something with the matrix. My problem is that I don't think the function is being properly passed from the functions, so I thought I need to declare it globally?

Comment: @Amit: I've addressed your comment in [an answer to your follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914641/passing-matrices-from-function-to-function-in-matlab/4915595#4915595).

Comment: So essentially, the reason is that in Matlab/Octave, unlike most languages, a `.m` file and a functions it contains are completely separate scopes?

Comment: In case we need to have to initialize the value of the global variable , how do we proceed? Like it's a MATLAB function and the global variable's value keeps changing with time.

Comment: @Aditi: If I understand correctly what you're asking... in your function you can check if the global variable has been initialized by checking if it [is empty](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) or not. If it has only been declared as a global but not given a specific value, its value should be `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

Referring to your comment towards gnovice using a global variable can be an approach to solve your issue, but it's not a commonly used.

First of all make sure that your `.m` files are *functions* and not *scripts*. *Scripts* share a common workspace, making it easy to unwillingly overwrite your variables. In contrast, functions have their own scope.

Use [xUnit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846-matlab-xunit-test-framework) in order to generate repeatable unit test for your functions. By testing each function involved in your program you will track down the error source. Having your unit test in place, further code modifications, can be easily verified.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What you said is definitely right, +1. Instead of using global vars, I now use the return value of the function and set that equal to whatever I want in the main function. It works a hell of a lot better and it's what I was going for initially, though I didn't know of a way to accomplish such tasks. It works beautifully now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to get around the `global` mess is to assign the variable as `appdata`. You can use the functions `setappdata` and `getappdata` to assign and retrieve `appdata` from a MATLAB window. As long as a MATLAB session is active there exists a window denoted by `0`.

```
>> setappdata(0,'x',10)  % 0 indicates the root MATLAB window
```

Now the variable x is not visible to any script or function but can be accessed wherever needed by using `getappdata`.

```
function test
    globalX = getappdata(0,'x');
    disp(globalX);
end

x =
    10
```

The good news is that you can assign any valid MATLAB object to `appdata`, just be cautious with the names, using unique names for appdata fields like `ModelOptimizerOptions` instead of a generic `x`,`y` would help. This works on compiled executables and code deployed on the MATLAB production server as well.