# Passing matrices from function to function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm pretty new to MATLAB and I have a simple question. What if I have the following structured functions:

```
function[A] = test(A)
test1(A);
test2(A);
end

function test1(A)
#% do something with A
end

function test2(A)
#% do something else with the newly modified A
end
```

How do I pass around A from function to function keeping it's modified nature? (Suppose A is a matrix)

EDIT: let's make the situation a little simpler. Suppose my main function is:

```
function[a]=test(a)
test1(a);
#%test2(a);
end
```

and `test1()` is defined as:

```
function[a] = test1(a)
a=5;
end
```

Then, I call the function `test` with `test(3)`, and I want it to report `ans = 5`, yet it still reports `ans = 3`.

Thanks!

Comment: I should mention this: Each function is in its own `.m` file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables in MATLAB are passed using "call by value" ([with some exceptions](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15SO4/?solution=1-15SO4)), so any value that you pass to a function and modify has to be returned from the function and either placed in a new variable or the old variable overwritten. Returning the value of a variable from a function is simple: you just place the variable name in the [output argument list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bresuxt-1.html#br67dei-1) for the function.

For your example, you would do this:

```
function A = test(A)
  A = test1(A);  %# Overwrite A with value returned from test1
  A = test2(A);  %# Overwrite A with value returned from test2
end

function A = test1(A)  %# Pass in A and return a modified A
  #% Modify A
end

function A = test2(A)  %# Pass in A and return a modified A
  #% Modify A
end
```

One thing to be aware of is [variable scope](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-38052.html#f0-38068). Every function has its own workspace to store its own local variables, so there are actually 3 unique `A` variables in the above example: one in the workspace of `test`, one in the workspace of `test1`, and one in the workspace of `test2`. Just because they are named the same doesn't mean they all share the same value.

For example, when you call `test1` from `test`, the value stored in the variable `A` in `test` is copied to the variable `A` in `test1`. When `test1` modifies its local copy of `A`, the value of `A` in `test` is unchanged. To update the value of `A` in `test`, the return value from `test1` has to be copied to it.

Comment: Thank you, I had figured this out earlier. This is a much more complete answer and deserves the check. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Return the object from the function and then pass it on to the next function.

Comment: I understand this is what I need to do. But how do I do it? In C, I would just `return A;`. But in MATLAB?

Comment: assign the value you want to return to the name of the function, e.g. `test1 = A*2;`