# When calling a function in matlab, how can I output the result to a matrix in the original file?

Tags: function, matlab, matrix, call

Basically I would like to call a function that I have written, and because of the amount of results, I would like the function to output its solution into a matrix that gets passed to the program that called it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing matrices from function to function in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914641/passing-matrices-from-function-to-function-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the output of a function in the function declaration at the top of your script:

```
function [output] = myFunction(input)
```

All you need to do is define the `output` variable somewhere in your script.

Answer (score 0):

The confusing part (to me) was that you need to put the output variables in both your main program and your function definition.  So in your main program you have:

[out1,out2,out3] = function_name(in1,in2);

and in your function definition, you have:

function  [out1,out2,out3] = function_name(in1,in2).

The variables don't have to have the same name, but they need to be oriented similarly, so that you can then pass the outputs back to the main program.