# Assign array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a question about the following code.

```
[name file] = uigetfile('*', 'Select an image');
if [name file] ~= 0
    %file found
end
```

Is there a way of saying that [name file] can be assigned to an array? For example, `Filepath[2] = ui.getfile..` (this doesn't work).

When I tried the following code, I only get the filename and not the path. Am I declaring this array wrong?

```
Filepath{2} = uigetfile({'*.wav;*.mp3;*.aac;*.ogg'}, 'Select a file');
%Filepath{2} = uigetfile('*', 'Select an image');
%noFile = Filepath(0);
%if Filepath[1]~= 0
%if Filepath ~= 0

disp('Loading signal');
disp(Filepath);
%disp(Filepath{0});
disp('Filepath{1}');
disp(Filepath{1});
disp('Filepath{2}');
disp(Filepath{2});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confused about the syntax for multiple "output arguments" of a function.  Unlike most programming languages, [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) allows functions to have multiple return values; these are called output arguments. When you have a function `[a b] = foo(x)`, it is best to think of this as just the syntax to send the first output to a variable called `a` and the second output to a variable called `b`. Even though the syntax `[a b]` looks like an array, it is best to not think of it that way.

Here's an example of `uigetfile`:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.m', 'Select a file');
```

which gives the filename and path of the selected file, in variables called `filename` and `pathname`, respectively.

```
filename =

foo.m


pathname =

/home/tobin/
```

> *But what I don't understand is that this method returns zero if it was canceled or a filled array if it was successfull. So how can I check for zero (file not found)?*

Why not try it out?

```
> [filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*', 'Select a file')

filename =

     0


pathname =

     0
```

It appears that both outputs are 0 if the `uigetfile` is cancelled. So you can do this:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*', 'Select a file');
fullname = horzcat(pathname, filename);
if filename == 0
    fprintf('uigetfile was cancelled.\n');
else
    fprintf('user selected "%s".\n', fullname);
end
```

Comment: And is there a way to globalise these variables [filename, pathname] so I can access them in other methods? I tried declaring them at the top as in other programming languages but that didn't work; also typing global in front of 'm did not work.

Comment: There is no need to declare variables in Matlab, nor any way to do so.

Comment: If you do `global filename pathname`, then `filename` and `pathname` will become global variables.  Unlike in other programming languages, you have to put the `global filename pathname` line in *every* function that will access these global variables.  See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911926/declaring-a-global-variable-in-matlab

Comment: Now I get it. One last question, could you refer (or write me) me to a good snippet where a custom function is used?

I would like to create a method for opening files and then always change the global variables instead of copy pasting the code everytime I wan't to open a file.

Comment: To make a custom function, you typically put the code in a dedicated file.  For instance, the function `myfunction` will live in `myfunction.m`.  For an example of how to declare a function in that file, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function.html .

Answer (score 2):

Array accesses in MATLAB use parentheses for "normal" arrays, or curly brackets for [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html). A "normal" array can only hold numeric values, so you'll have to use a cell array -- so try `Filepath{2} = uigetfile(...)`.