# Global variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, global-variables

let us consider following code which declares global variable in matlab function

```
function[y] = myfun2(x)
global b

a = 3;
y = x.^4.*sqrt(a*x+5)./(x.^2+b);
b = 4;
```

then following commands

```
global b;
>> b=1

b =

     1

>> y=myfun2(3)
```

returns me value

```
 y =

   30.3074
```

i have first question there  why it is necessary to declare global variable second times?is it not enough to declare it inside function?and also my second question

following command

```
y=myfun2(3)

y =

   23.3134
```

does it means that second times it  used   number 4?how can i determine which b  is used first time?i meant 1 or 4?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dato datuashvili,

You are confused with global variable.

**Ordinarily, each MATLAB® function has its own local variables, which are separate from those of other functions, and from those of the base workspace. However, if several functions, and possibly the base workspace, all declare a particular name as global, they all share a single copy of that variable. Any assignment to that variable, in any function, is available to all the functions declaring it global.
If the global variable does not exist the first time you issue the global statement, it is initialized to the empty matrix.
If a variable with the same name as the global variable already exists in the current workspace, MATLAB issues a warning and changes the value of that variable to match the global.**

Have a look on this page, which is also source of my answer.

http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/global.html

In addition to that,

**You need to declare x as a global variable in every scope (i.e. function/workspace) that you want it to be shared across. So, you need to write test1 as:**

```
function test1()
  global x;
  x = 5;
end
```

The source to above answer is [Declaring a global variable in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911926/declaring-a-global-variable-in-matlab).
If that does not help you, please notify me.

Comment: so in my case,first time it used which variable  1?because there was declared global variable  b and assign then i to  workspace

Comment: as i mentioned you need to declare global in every scope, other wise it would be considered local variable and values will differ.There are possibility to get warnings.

Comment: one more question,if i would not assign  b  to 4 in function,what would be result?

Comment: no,even i would not assign b=1,it takes empty matrix as input right?

Comment: actually you are overwriting, ex: when b=4 //b is now 4; b=1 //now b is 1; // here ownwards b=1 , no mean of second time, it's always 1

Comment: i mean different one,if i  would not declare b=1 in workspace and also i would not assigne b=4 in the function

Comment: that's not possible, you have to give something

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you.