# global variable in octave

Tags: global, octave

```
global m = 1;
function p = h()
  m
end
h()
```

I'm trying to run this script, but I get this error:

> 'm' undefined near line 4 column 3

Say me please, how I can use the variable from functions?

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Global-Variables.html). This addressed exactly in one of the very first examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring a global variable in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911926/declaring-a-global-variable-in-matlab) -this is a Matlab-tagged question, but the solution is identical for Octave.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to declare the var also global inside the function as described here:  https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Global-Variables.html

```
global m = 1;
function p = h()
  global m;
  m
endfunction
h()
```

Comment: How to change the global variable from the function then?

Comment: like you would change any other var: assign a new value to it. What have you tried so far?