# Storing and accessing matrix operated inside a function parallelized by pararrayfun of Octave/Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, octave

Pararrayfun is used this way

```
pkg load parallel;
# fun is the function to apply 
fun = @(x) x^2;
vector_x = 1:10000;
vector_y = pararrayfun(16, fun, vector_x);
```

I intend to apply it to a function with this form

```
fun = @(i) zz(1:100,i+1) = z.^2;
```

where z is a column vector, and zz is a 100xi matrix. I want to get the matrix zz out after the pararrayfun() but I get nothing back. I dont know if I am using the right code or the right argument as I have just started using octave a month ago. Any help would really be appreciated.

Here is my attempted "full" code:

```
pkg load parallel;
z = linspace(-1,10,100).';
fun = @(i) zz(1:100,i+1) = z.^2;
i = 0:9999;
pararrayfun(16, fun, i);
```

I tried to use global zz but I still get nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer is that the `zz` variable inside you `fun` is a local variable. It would have to be declared as [`global`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27410799/3565696), but this is not possible inside an [anonymous function](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Anonymous-Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions) (defined with `@() ...`).

One might be tempted to try to define `fun` with

```
pkg load parallel;
z = linspace(-1,10,100).';
global zz
zz = zeros(100, 10000);
function fun1(idx, z)
  global zz
  zz(:, idx) = z.^2;
endfunction

fun = @(idx) fun1(idx, z)

idx = 1:10000;
pararrayfun(nproc, fun, idx);
```

But the `zz` is not modified. Probably because each thread has its own context.

This is a good thing, because otherwise modifying a global variable inside a `pararrayfun` call would lead to potential race conditions.

Here is a safer way:

```
pkg load parallel;
z = linspace(-1,10,100).';
fun = @(i) z.^2;
idx = 1:10000;
zz = pararrayfun(nproc, fun, idx);
```

As a side note, for this example,

```
zz = repmat(z, 1, 10000);
```

would be much faster.

Comment: Nice, detailed answer but I'm afraid this doesn't help the OP (due to XY-problem). Btw, the parallel package uses `fork` on GNU/Linux (and is not of much use on windoze) and thus can't "store" values in globals so that the parent process can access them

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Andy Exactly, this is what I meant by "each thread has its own context". So the answer was "not possible" with `pararrayfun`, to the best of my knowledge.