# MATLAB: Accessing a variable created in a program

Tags: matlab, global-variables

For the program, for example:

```
function output = input(n)
global SAVER;
SAVER = zeros(n,n,20);
*other code here*
output = SAVER(:,:,5)
```

When this is run in the command window (by `input(5)` for example), the variable `ans` appears in the workspace.

However, I was under the impression that because `SAVER` was declared as a global variable, it would also be saved globally and would be accessible from the workspace.

However, when I type `SAVER(:,:,2)` for example in the command window after running `input(n)` I get the error message `Undefined function or variable 'SAVER'`.

Is it possible to access the different elements in `SAVER` from the command window after running the function, and is this not what a global variable does?

Comment: Just run `global SAVER` in the command window as well before trying to access `SAVER` there.

Comment: Possible dublication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911926/declaring-a-global-variable-in-matlab