# set input value from GUI into global variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

i have problem with matlab gui that when i set it global variable not work and not shown in work space table
also i would to use it in more than function how to use it i tryed this code but not worked
the idea that i set poin x , y , z then i want to made offset with this points so i need to use it as global variables

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global Ref_x;
global Ref_y;
global Ref_z;
px=str2double(get(handles.pos_x,'string'))+Ref_x;
py=str2double(get(handles.pos_y,'string'))+Ref_y;
pz=str2double(get(handles.pos_z,'string'))+Ref_z;
```

Comment: Did you set the variables as global in the other functions where you wanted to use them?

Comment: ↑ That, and also in 'base' workspace.

Comment: Both above comments are right, it would have been rather obvious if you had try to read the documentation for [`global`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declaring a global variable in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911926/declaring-a-global-variable-in-matlab)